# MongoEngine & Pymongo Error when save (any) document to collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I receive the following error when trying to save a document to a collection:

```
mongoengine.errors.OperationError: Could not save document (assertion src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/btree/key.cpp:626)
```

The collection (and the db) exists and I've tried to empty it, remove any index in it, and nothing works: I keep receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing: `sudo mongod --repair` everything works normally.